# 1st time log in issues username/password

Tags: password

Help! I am in school and need the virtual machine mainly for practice. I have installed Virtual Box and Ubuntu. However, when I try to open a virtual machine, Ubuntu wants me to log in. I went ahead and created an Ubuntu user account, but I cannot sign in with it. I have tried several suggestions I have seen in the forum, such as ubuntu as the user and several different passwords.

Chat does not work as they are not technical support, and I was only advised to read the forums and email customer service who "may" get back to me.

grrrr...

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the forum! What do you mean by "cannot sign in"? It says you typed in the wrong password?

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu in the virtual Box, It should have prompted you to create an username and password. If you didn't get such a prompt, [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1441453/edit) and describe how exactly did you install Ubuntu in VB?  Which version did you install? Where did you get it from? How did you create an user account after installation without logging in?

Comment: Yes, it says that it is an incorrect password. I was not prompted to create an account. I simply went to Ubuntu.com and registered. When that didn't work, I also went into my Ubuntu account and reset the password just to make sure... I still cannot get in